# When are global javascript variables reset?

Tags: javascript, performance

If I set a global variable in my HTML page, like this:

```
window.MY_VAR = "just a test";
```

When will MY_VAR be 'unloaded' from the global scope? Does this happen automatically if a user navigates to another page within the same website? When do I need to delete MY_VAR manually to prevent it gobbling up memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user moves to another *page*, i.e. the URL in the address bar changes and/or the whole page *unloads* and another page *loads*, the entire Javascript environment is scrapped, including global variables. As long as you stay on the same page, the environment and variables stay too.

Answer (score -1):

You can unset a Javascript variable with `delete window.MY_VAR;`.

Otherwise, global variables will be reset each time a page loads.